# Not Able To Fix Width in my phonegap Application

Tags: android, css, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap application development. [Here](http://pastie.org/4164072) is my html code.

My query is that I am not able to fix horizontal scrolling. I want to disable horizontal scrolling but not able to get any effect. Line number 35 of my html page contains main div tag of my html page. I have tried by fixing width as 320px, 100% etc. but in vain.

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong ?